# Does the magus' pool strike count as a touch spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, touch-attacks

The pfsrd states that,

> whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack.

One of his magus arcana lets him make an energy touch attack, but it's a supernatural ability, not a spell per se. Does it still work with his Spellstrike ability? That is, can I deliver this energy attack through my weapon?

magus page:
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate questions here, and they have two different answers.

Regarding the first question, whether or not Pool Strike counts as a "touch spell": No. Pool strike is *not* a spell of any kind, touch or otherwise, and nothing in its text or any of the other Magus text changes that.

Regarding the second question, whether or not it can be used with Spellstrike: Yes. Pool Strike's text explicitly states that it does work with Spellstrike. This does *not* make Pool Strike a spell, it simply overrides the requirement for it to be one, so that these abilities can still be used together, despite Pool Strike not being a spell.

Answer (score -1):

No and yes. No, it is not a *touch spell* but yes, it works with *Spellstrike*.

Essentially Spellstrike allows you to unleash Pool Strike damage with every melee attack as long as you have just one point of arcane power left in your pool.

Comment: The quote in the question states pretty explicitly that it only applies “whenever a magus **casts** a **spell**,” which are not words that apply to supernatural abilities. Is there an FAQ or anything else that you can quote that suggests that spellstrike applies to this ability as well?

Comment: if you look above, it was explained that the Pool strike description states that you can use Spellstrike.[link]http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/pool-strike-su_

Comment: You should add that to your answer then. It is important that answers here always back up their claims. Just say that the Pool Strike arcana itself explicitly allows itself to work with spellstrike, and provide the link, and this will be a great answer.

Comment: I understand that buddy, but It was part of the previous answer, so there was no need to repeat that.

Comment: Yes, indeed; I don’t really see why we needed another answer that says the same thing. But if you’re going to add another answer,  the same expectations are going to be made of your answer as others, i.e. you are still expected to back up your answer. If anything, the standards are *higher*, since it doesn’t really seem like your answer adds anything than Matthew’s didn’t already cover.

Comment: Well, since i am so new to this forum and your expectations, would you mind telling me how to report you for harassing me unnecessarily? @KRyan

Comment: If you feel that you are being harassed, unnecessarily or otherwise, you can Flag the post to bring it to moderator attention. In the case of comments, flagging is done by hovering over the comment, and clicking the flag icon. You can also bring up any policy disagreements you may have on [Meta] if you like.

Comment: Note that the expectations described above are community expectations, not personal expectations.